# JPA Entities are not managed / relations not persisted

Tags: java, spring, jpa, orm, jboss

### Setup

I'm Using JPA 1.0, Spring 3.0.6 and hibernate 3.2.1 on JBoss 4.3.2. There are some EJBs which at some point call a DAO which tries to persist two entities.

### Problem

The result is quite unexpected: **The entities are not managed after calling .persist(entity)**.

The Funny thing is: A quite similar test app, which uses the same jars containing DAOs, Beans persistence.xml as the server application, persists everything just fine. The beans are managed after calling `.persist()`.

### The entities

I have a class `Subscriber` that has a `SubscriberState`.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "subscriber")
public class Subscriber implements java.io.Serializable {

    // all the other stuff

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "status")
    private SubscriberState state;

}
```

For legacy reasons the `SubscriberState` has a relation `Subscriber`.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "subscriber_state")
public class SubscriberState implements java.io.Serializable {

    // ...blah

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "subscriber", nullable = false)
    private Subscriber subscriber;
}
```

### what i do to persist

Now i try to persist a subscriber, it will be unmanaged afer persist():

```
 final Subscriber subscriber = new Subscriber();
 // set up...
 entityManager.persist(subscriber);
 entityManager.contaons(subscriber); //will yield FALSE
```

Adding a `SubscriberState` will work. But only one side of the relation will be stored to DB:

```
SubscriberState subscriberState = new SubscriberState();
subscriberState.setSubscriber(subscriber);
entityManager.persist(subscriberState);
entityManager.merge(subscriber);
```

where `SubscriberState.setSubscriber` looks like this:
    public void setSubscriber(final Subscriber subscriber) {
         this.subscriber = subscriber;
        subscriber.setState(this);
    }

A look at the database shows me, that the `SubscriberState` knows it's `Subscriber`, but the Subscriber does not know it's `State`.

### the config

Here's the (now modified and stripped down) persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
```

org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence
        java:jdbc/SODS

```
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="${db.hibernate.dialect}" />
        <property name="hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.validator.autoregister_listeners" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.jboss.ejb3.entity.TreeCacheProviderHook" />
        <property name="hibernate.treecache.mbean.object_name" value="jboss.cache:service=EJB3EntityTreeCache" />
        <property name="jboss.entity.manager.jndi.name" value="java:/SOEntityManager-${app.version}" />
        <property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name" value="java:/SOEntityManagerFactory-${app.version}" />
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory" />
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup" />
    </properties>

    <class>com.stackoverflow.some.classes.i.cant.show.Here</class>
```

and here are the relevant parts of my spring context:

```
    <context:annotation-config />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true" />

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="entityManagerFactory" jndi-name="java:/SOEntityManagerFactory-${app.version}" />
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="entityManager" jndi-name="java:/SOEntityManager-${app.version}" />
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="soDataSource" jndi-name="java:jdbc/SODS" />

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager" />

    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="soDataSource" />
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="blah - secret" />
    <import resource="daoContext.xml" />
</beans>
```

Any ideas, why this config won't work?

Comment: What happens if you remove the logic from subscriberState.setSubscriber(subscriber) and only set the subscriber, and call subscriber.setState(subscriberState); as well?  Contains returning false is odd, but the subscriber gets into the database or there would be a constraint violation when subscriberState tries to references it.

Comment: can't test that yet. resources were redistributed, other projects take preference. But i'll check if i get to work on this again!

Comment: Did you receive any exception ?, or just entities are not stored?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see use of @Transaction in your DAO or service layer

*Adding a SubscriberState will work. But only one side of the relation will be stored to DB*

You should use cascade option in

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name = "subscriber", nullable = false)
private Subscriber subscriber;
```

This will save both side of the relationship in persist operation

Also what I see is two unidirectional relationship, not one bidireccional, try to use mappedBy

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "status")
private SubscriberState state;
```

Unless that is not what you want, but you should reconsider your design to made one side OneToMany and the other side ManyToOne, use mappedBy to define the source (owner) of the relationship

Comment: I can't redesign it. This is (sadly) not what i (=my client) wants. There is a transaction wrapped around my DAO, btw.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to my application, JPA with MySQL. Load the appropriate database driver class in the property file.